# Web Browser-File System Integration

Tags: internet-explorer, user-interface, google-chrome, integration, desktop

I was reading about this old project by Microsoft in 96 called Windows Nashville. There wasn't much about it, but what interested me was the ability to, say, replace your wallpaper with a dynamic webpage, and explore the Web from your desktop, literally. It wouldn't have been much with IE 3.0, but I think it's a shame they didn't develop on it later. Or maybe not.

Anyway, I was wondering if I could make a web browser GUI that allowed this, where the regular desktop and Internet are integrated. That reminds me of Chrome OS. Could I invent my own sort of GUI developed on these principles?

Cheers for any response.

Comment: Just as an aside, this has been in mainstream Windows installation as the Active Desktop until as recently as Vista. You can always use 'Windows Desktop Gadgets' on Win 7. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Desktop

Answer (score 0):

Well, surely someone could. It's not theoretically impossible. You tell us if you can...